# How to know exactly what window is being interacted by user?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

I want to check what window is being interacted with window_handle, but after changing window with my mouse, the current_window_handle was the same.

How can I solve that problem ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't detect what's happening with the browser outside of the code running. It has a window handle and that window handle doesn't change if you mess with the browser manually by switching tabs, etc.